# Viewing rule-flow files in drools-guvnor

Tags: bpmn, drools-flow, drools-guvnor

I'm working on a project that involves creating work-flows, in Drools flow.
I have a lot of rule flow (rf) files, that I want to be available for viewing through a web UI.

I've seen that drools-guvnor allows management of rf files. But it seems that it does not allow users to view them (only downloading works).

I've also heard that the bpmn file format works with Guvnor, but in my work-flows, i need to use global objects, which i don't think are supported.

So my queries are,
Is there a way to display rf files on Guvnor?
and
Can globals be used in bpmn files?

Comment: No matter, It seems that I was using an outdated version of drools.
The latest version, along with the eclipse plugin, allows creation of BMPN2 processes which can handle globals and imports.
Moreover the eclipse plugin allows conversion from rf to bpmn easily